# Does the size of a document in a vertex collection influence the performance in a graph search?

Tags: data-structures, graph, arangodb

Can the speed of a graph operation in a AQL query be affected by the size of the documents in the vertex collection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. In general: the bigger the documents/edges are that are processed, the longer a query might take in theory. The effect might not be noticable however, and also depends on how you access the data in these documents/edges.

If you build up a result set containing lots of *big* documents/edges, and this result set will be constructed as the query result (or as an internal temporary result), then creating bigger documents/edges will take more memory and processing time than if the documents/edges were smaller.

In general, you should try to keep the results, and this includes temporary results from function calls and graph actions, as small as possible.